# What is a DesignInstance in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I actually learn the MVVM-Pattern and I found in a Tutorial this:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance step1:ViewModel}">
```

I know that I use the Data Context to bind Data but what I don´t understand is for what the DesignInstance is usefull and why I write it down there ?

On the MSDN HP stands: "DesignInstance is a design-time property." But I can´t do anything with that do.

Edit:
The Tutorial Step 1 from http://www.learnmvvm.com/tutorial.html#step1-1

Comment: It's so the editor can show you intellisense since it has a type to get properties from. The d: namespace is ignored when you run your application so it's only for designing your view.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The design instance is used when the view is opened in the visual studio editor.

Say you have a view that uses a list view to display a list of products, and you use a template to display each product. Without a viewmodel, your view will not display anything, and you can't really see what the view will look like in the application.

You don't want to run your entire app, with all its dependencies from the editor. Instead supply a design instance, with some stub data that makes the view render some products. Think of it as some fake test data that makes your view render correctly in the editor.

Comment: Ah ok then DesignData is also a Dummy ?

Comment: Yes, both are dummies!

Answer (score 3):

You may define the view model for your view through a dependency injection framework like Cariburn or simply set the view model in the code behind therefore your view will run and work perfectly but since the view model is not explicitly defined in the view XAML file, the visual studio XAML designer does not have a clue where to navigate to when you want to navigate to the view model properties bound in the view. using `DesignInstance` with the right type will make the designer able to navigate to the view model properties for you.