# How to set DataContext type in xaml, when it is assigned in code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm assigning my viewModel to `DataContext` in my code-behind constructor.

It works, but my IDE does not recognize bindings in XAML. How can I "tell" viewModel's type to XAML without creating it there?

I wish I assigned DataContext in XAML directly, like:

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

but due to some reasons my viewModel's constructor is not public.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695456/what-is-a-designinstance-in-xaml

Comment: Could you convert your comment to an answer or make my question duplicate? @KlausGütter